# Hibernate saveOrUpdate, update needs all fields of original row

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using mysql and hibernate to insert and update rows in a table. I use saveOrUpdate call. Now, When I try to update a row in a table, I get a exception. Exception states that my column requestTime cannot be null. Obviously its true since I have setup the column property to be NotNull.

I am able to add the row. But when update it with values of 2 more columns, I get this exception.

I am assuming that when I update, I need to read the row from the table, and update the entire row. Is that true ? I was kinda hoping that hibernate saveOrUpdate would do it for me. So I have a Object that has getters for all the columns when I insert a new row. But when I update I have a Object that only has getters for the primary key and new columns.

```
Transaction txD;
Session session;
session = currentSession();
txD = session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(dataStore);
txD.commit();
```

Exception

```
749368 [Thread-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  - com.mcruiseon.carpool.concrete.SubscribeProviderConcrete{acceptedTime=Mon Jul 30 03:39:23 UTC 2012, requestTime=null, subscriberIdentityHash=1218553253, requestIdentity=167093126, subscribedProviderHash=-284086361, isAccepted=true}
749375 [Thread-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - update carPoolSubscribedProvider set subscriberIdentityHash=?, requestTime=?, subscribedProviderHash=?, isAccepted=?, acceptedTime=? where requestIdentity=?
749398 [Thread-2] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Column 'requestTime' cannot be null [n/a]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'requestTime' cannot be null
```

select * from carPoolSubscribedProvider

```
+-----------------+------------------------+---------------------+------------------------+------------+--------------+
| requestIdentity | subscriberIdentityHash | requestTime         | subscribedProviderHash | isAccepted | acceptedTime |
+-----------------+------------------------+---------------------+------------------------+------------+--------------+
| 167093126       | -284086361             | 2012-07-27 16:13:19 | 1218553253             |          0 | NULL         |
+-----------------+------------------------+---------------------+------------------------+------------+--------------+
```

Edit :

```
| carPoolSubscribedProvider | CREATE TABLE `carPoolSubscribedProvider` (
  `requestIdentity` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `subscriberIdentityHash` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `requestTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `subscribedProviderHash` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isAccepted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `acceptedTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`requestIdentity`),
```

Comment: Do I need to have a different flow of code for update vs insert ? Something like if (update) { row=getColumn(primaryKey), appendValues(row, newValues) } else insert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate cannot figure out how you want attribute with null value be treted. It cannot make difference between cases where:

1. some attribute is null -> should set to null in database
2. some attribute is null -> should not update such an attribute.

Setting value for attribute that was previously non-null to null means that value of attribute should be changed.

If you want to make column never be part of update statement, you can set updatable attribute to false in [@Column](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#updatable%28%29) annotation. According documentation it defines: *Whether the column is included in SQL UPDATE statements generated by the persistence provider*

Comment: Can i get hibernate to ignore column values if null on a update ?

Comment: At least I am not aware how to ignore it in the case of null. If applicable, you can make it never be part of update.

Answer (score 1):

If you write your table definition will be easier.

There are two case for your not null column:

1. You have a "default value".

```
 
    create table t1
    (
        id integer not null,
        column1 char not null default 'Y',
        column2 date not null default sysdate,
        column3 varchar2(30) not null default user,
        intcol integer not null default 12
    );
```

if you not specify in INSERT or UPDATE this columns, oracle automatically will put default value in table.

1. You **don't** have a "default value".

```
    create table t1
    (
        id integer not null,
        column1 char not null,
        column2 date not null ,
        column3 varchar2(30) not null,
        intcol integer default 12
    );
```

if you not specify in INSERT or UPDATE this columns, oracle automatically throw you an error messages.

This is theory about not null in database, let's go to Hibernate:

you can put in column annotation something like this:

```
 insert="false", update="false"
```

Then database will use a default value, but if in your table definition default is not specified then value of this field should be always be not null.

EDIT:

So I see now you have 3 columns "NOT NULL". 
For column where you have a definied default 'requestIdentity' you can use a dynamic update, or dynami insert: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

But for rest of them you have to put value in variable:

```
private Date requestTime = new Date();

private String subscriberIdentityHash = "someDefaultHashHere";
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited the question with the table definition, where should i be putting the annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

oUp = Updated row with null fields & 
oDb = Row fetched from database at update time

```
public static <T> T updateChanges(T oDb, T oUp) {
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = oDb.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(oUp) != null) {
                field.set(oDb, field.get(oUp));
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return oDb;
}
```